# Only one item may be clicked on recyclerView android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I've a recycler view on my app. I'd like to prevent multi selections on my recyclerView, because I'm getting unexpected output while trying to delete items.

```
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (null != mListener) {
            mListener.onPreviewItemClicked(position);

            if (holder.isSelected) {
                holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                Log.d("positionClicked adapter",position+"");
                holder.isSelected = false;
                isSelected = holder.isSelected;
            } else {
                holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, (R.color.accent_light)));
                holder.isSelected = true;
                positionClicked = position;
                isSelected = holder.isSelected;
            }
        }
    });
```

On my code, I use *is Selected* boolean to catch if something is clicked. When I click on an item, background of its changes. The thing is :

If I click on item1, then on item2, both items have backgrounds changed, and I'd like to have only one. And when I click on item, code below is done. But then, If i click again on item2, it goes transparent, which is good ! But the position of my item selected  is wrong ( should be 1, but it's 2 because last item selected was 2). So when I delete, it will delete 2nd item and not first one...

I delete using *positionClicked* variable.

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep if item is selected in your model, and use it in the `onBindViewHolder` to setup background for the ViewHolder. In `OnClickListener` just set `true` for the specific data item, false for all others and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to rebinf all items.